# How to browse folders in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I have a folder and inside that, few files. How can i get that files without using any UI classes?

The small eg given below will make question more clearer:

Suppose in my home folder, there is a folder Printers, inside that there are three folders Printer1, Printer2, Printer3. Now inside each subfolder there is xml file like printer1.xml inside printer1 folder, printer2.xml inside printer2 folder, printer3.xml inside printer3 folder. I have to browse through the folders and store the path to printer3.xml in a variable (of type NSString).

Please suggest me the ways to do that..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to use [NSFileManager](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and related classes..[This](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_Directories_in_Objective-C#Getting__a_Directory_File_Listing) tutorial might be useful too..

Answer (score 1):

You can use NsFileManger to read directories and files,
here a sample of using FileManager to read documents dir file

```
//Object file manager
NSFileManager *FileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
//Read Program folder and create an Array with all folder
NSArray *Paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

//Element in 0 position contain Documents directory 

//Faccio la dir dei file della directory
Files = [FileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[Paths objectAtIndex:0] error:nil];

if(Files) {
    //E uno per uno li cancello
    for (NSString *File in Files) {
        //Here YOU CAN CREATE YOUR STRING, File CONTAINS file Name

    }
}
```